# No nautilus on desktop after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

I have lost file manager functionality as well as right click on my desktop after upgrading to 12.04. Everything else in Unity works fine. Restarting nautilus does not work. Additionally, Unity Launcher reacts very slowly when all windows are minimized.

PC: Samsung N150Plus with upgraded RAM (2GB now).

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Can you please open a terminal by hitting Ctrl+Alt+T and give the command: 'nautilus' (without the quotes) and paste here the output so as to see what causes the error?

Comment: what about gnome tweak tool, http://www.noobslab.com/2011/10/install-gnome-tweak-tool-in-ubuntu-1110.html the option to "let file browser manage the desktop" does that do anything?

Answer (score 2):

mateo_salta suggested a possible solution in a comment that may work for some people experiencing this problem:

> what about gnome tweak tool,
>   [noobslab.com/2011/10/…](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/10/install-gnome-tweak-tool-in-ubuntu-1110.html)
>   the option to "let file browser manage the desktop" does that do
>   anything?

– [mateo_salta](https://askubuntu.com/users/47291/mateo-salta) [May 27 '12 at 19:31](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129156/no-nautilus-on-desktop-after-upgrade-to-12-04#comment171428_129156)

<sub>That page (the article, probably not the comments, advertisements, etc.) is licensed (see the banner under the copyright statement) [CC-BY 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/), which permits inclusion of it here, in any part of it, with or without modification, so long as proper attribution is given. (This is because user-contributed content here is [licensed](http://stackexchange.com/legal) under [CC-BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).)</sub>

> ### Install GNOME Tweak Tool in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin/Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot
>
> #### General tweaks (for both GNOME Shell and Unity) Change themes, fonts and more with GNOME Tweak Tool
>
> http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-AV91jNOQrOA/TpcXSq-7kwI/AAAAAAAAFBU/NTPZW2iky0c/s1600/gnome-tweak-tool.png">
>
> Features:
>
> - Install and switch gnome-shell themes
> - Switch gtk/icon/cursor themes
> - Switch window manager themes
> - Change
>
>   - The user-interface and titlebar fonts
>   - Icons in menus and buttons
>   - Behavior on laptop lid close
>   - Shell font size
>   - File manager desktop icons
>   - Titlebar click action
>   - Shell clock to show date
>   - Font hinting and antialiasing
>
> In Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot there is no built in themes and icon
>   changer in Oneiric, So easily you can use Gnome Tweak Tools for
>   changing themes and icons in Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric.
>
> **To install in Ubuntu open Terminal and copy the following command in the Terminal:**
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
> ```
>
> When installation complete, GNOME Tweak Tool should show up as
>   "Advanced Settings" in the menu. Besides changing fonts or themes,
>   GNOME Tweak Tool can also be used to disable/enable GNOME Shell
>   extensions, tweak the desktop, various windows behavior or GNOME
>   Shell.

***Source:*** [Install GNOME Tweak Tool in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin/Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/10/install-gnome-tweak-tool-in-ubuntu-1110.html) by [Umair](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=site:noobslab.com%20umair), posted 10/13/2011 on [Noobs Lab (blog)](http://www.noobslab.com/) – **with slight modification** (formatting, capitalization, and image alt text).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop -y && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-deskop
```

It removes the meta package `ubuntu-desktop` then reinstalls it, taking all the lost/new dependencies along with it.

Pay attention that ALL of the default software you uninstalled will be reinstalled again!

That's the simplest solution and usually 40% of issues like that are solved. Hoping it helps!

Comment: Why would this work? Purging `ubuntu-desktop` is the same as uninstalling (it's a metapackage with no systemwide config files). This removes no software, as purging/removing a metapackage leaves its dependencies intact. (You could then run `apt-get` with `autoremove` to remove its dependencies, but that could be a disaster, as you could lose lots and lots of stuff!) Reinstalling the it potentially gets new dependencies, but `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` would too. (It doesn't go to a new Ubuntu release, see [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html).)

Comment: Dear Eliah, that command is not intended to remove anything more than the meta-package. As you said, purge or remove has no difference.. Because of that, purge or remove is just a preference in this case, and I prefer to purge =)

I don't want to run any autoremove, in fact I didn't wrote that.

So, I basically achieved the same result you suggested with sudo apt-get dist-upgrade, but I forced the upgrade of just ubuntu-desktop (and relative dependencies).

Why won't this work? =)

Comment: I'm not sure why that *would* help here, but I'll try to respond... This won't work because upgrading a package (a metapackage, or otherwise) only causes a dependency to be upgraded when the (meta)package's *version* requirements for the dependency have changed. What you've recommended doesn't do anything more than would be achieved by `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. That upgrades the metapackage just as well. If you want all packages upgraded, run `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.